# Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified selector does not match any node in the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am working with testCafe for the first time and I am trying to write a test that clicks the name of a specific patient in a list of patients displayed.

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> Cannot obtain information about the node because the specified
> selector does not match any node in the DOM tree.
>
> > | Selector('[data-cy=Name]')

This is the actual code block:

```
test
  .meta({
    code: '4.1',
    action: 'From Patient Summaries screen, click a patient name'.
    expected: 'Should take user to the weekly Patient Overview screen'
  })
  .page(url)
  ('4.1', async t => {
    await LoginPageObject.loginAsDoctor();

    const patients = Selector('[data-cy=Patients]');
    const settingsMenuItem = Selector('[data-cy=name]');

    await t.expect(patients.visible).ok().click(patients);
    await t.expect(Selector('[data-cy=table-row-0]').visible).ok()

    await t.expect(settingsMenuItem.textContent)
      .contains("Charles Shetland")
      .click(settingsMenuItem);

    await VnVScreenshot(t, '4.1', fixtureName);
  });
```

I tried doing `const settingsMenuItem = Selector('td [data-cy=Name]');` and `.contains("Shetland,Charles")` as that's technically how the name is listed.

But I am still getting the same error for `Selector('td [data-cy=Name]')`.

The way the DOM hierarchy looks is:

```
div
 table
  thead
  tbody
   tr
    td
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I was able to resole it is with some testCafe magic.

What I did was change the `data-cy="Name"`, to `data-cy="call_Shetland Charles"`.

I was not sure at first but that allowed me to go from this:

```
const settingsMenuItem = Selector('[data-cy=Name]');
```

To this:

```
const settingsMenuItem = Selector('[data-cy*=Charles]');
```

And testCafe was able to identify what patient I wanted it to click on.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to determine the exact cause of the error without a sample. However, I found the incorrect code in the following lines:

```
await t.expect(settingsMenuItem.textContent)
      .contains("Charles Shetland")
      .click(settingsMenuItem);
```

If you want to click an item with specified text, you need to use the `withText` method:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402740/reference/test-api/selector/withtext

```
await t.click(settingsMenuItem.withText('Charles Shetland'))
```

If this does not help, please prepare a sample that demonstrates the issue.

Please note that you can use the TestCafe Experimental Debug functionality to execute a selector in IDE or chrome nodejs console. Refer to the following article for details:
https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#--experimental-debug

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter issues with choosing a selector, use the selector generator available as part of the [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger) feature.